# Can I run Docker-in-Docker without using the --privileged flag

Tags: security, docker

I'd like to use [Docker-in-Docker](https://github.com/jpetazzo/dind) however the --privileged gives blanket access to devices. Is there a way to run this using a combination of volumes and cap-add etc. instead?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately no, you must use the `--privileged` flag to run Docker in Docker, you can take a look at the [official announcement](https://www.docker.com/blog/docker-can-now-run-within-docker/) where they state this is one of the many purposes of the `--privileged` flag.

Basically, you need more access to the host system devices to run docker than you get when running without `--privileged`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it doesn't look like this will change any time soon either - https://github.com/jpetazzo/dind/issues/60

Comment: What devices does docker in docker specifically require?  There's the `--device` option which is meant as sort of a less invasive privileged option.  [See docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#/runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can run docker in docker without the `--privileged` flag. It involves mounting the docker socket to the container like so:

```
   docker run -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
               -v $(which docker):/bin/docker \
               alpine docker ps -a
```

That is going mount the docker socket and executable into the container and run `docker ps -a` within the alpine container. Jérôme Petazzoni, who authored the the dind example and did a lot of the work on the `--privileged` flag had this to say about docker in docker:

https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/

I have been using this approach for a while now and it works pretty good.

The caveat with this approach is things get funky with storage. You're better off using data volume containers or named data volumes rather than mounting directories. Since you're using the docker socket from the host, any directories you want to mount with in a child container need to be from the context of the host, not the parent container. It gets weird. I have had better luck with data volume containers.

Comment: No it shouldn't, giving the container access to the hosts docker socket doesn't really solve the problem.

Comment: Actually this is not what dind (Docker-in-Docker) means. You are just running the docker client in a docker container, not a docker server in a docker container (dind). Besides, you are actually giving more attack surface by exposing the host socket than just adding the `--privileged` flag to the dind container and letting it have its own socket.

Comment: This is a huge security hole. You should not really use this anywhere outside of your development machine where you completely control the container workload.

Comment: I would not agree that Socket is more dangerous than `--privileged`. At least from what I understood in the blog post of the developer implementing the privileged flag:
https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/

Answer (score -3):

Yes. There are dind-rootless versions of docker image in docker hub.

https://hub.docker.com/_/docker

Comment: > just like the regular dind images, --privileged is required for Docker-in-Docker to function properly